# Change selected data.frame columns using value in first row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have created a table that show how much time each person in a team has spend for tasks each month.

```
Empl_level  team_member 2022/05 2022/06 2022/07 2022/08
0             department  117       69      73      30
1             Diana       108       108     113     184
1             Irina       90        63      56      40
2             Inga        77        56      74      30
3             Elina       23        35      58      79
```

However there is such "team member" as department. how to to create a new dataset, where time from the sell department will be equally divided by real team members

```
Empl_level  team_member    2022/05      2022/06 
1             Diana       108+(117/4)   108+(69/4)      
1             Irina       90+(117/4)    63+(69/4)       
2             Inga        77+(117/4)    etc.
3             Elina       23+(117/4)
```

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/10366237

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`, something like the following could work:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[,  names(df)[-(1:2)] := lapply(.SD, function(x)  {x + x[1]/4}), .SDcols = !1:2][-1]
```

The `[-1]` at the end removes the first "department" row.

Comment: Hi, thank for the reply, but when I try the code it returns me an error: mydata4[, lapply(.SD, function(x)  {x + x[1]/13}), .SDcols = -1:2]
Error in `[.data.table`(mydata4, , lapply(.SD, function(x) { : 
  .SDcols is numeric but has both +ve and -ve indices
>

Comment: @Диана I think I realise what was going wrong. Try the code now?

Comment: In new version in returns me an error : Error in names(mydata4)[-1:2] : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
>

Comment: I will create a sample set )

Comment: Whoops, forgot about that detail. Try now? With brackets, should work.

Comment: Sorry to bother again... now I have transposed the table, as rows i have dates and as columns I have names. And now I have to do the same  task of getting rid of "department" and additing the time from this table to other tables... How could I modify the code?

Comment: @Диана I would suggest maybe a new question, since rows and columns are not super interchangable in the code above.